# Launch AppleScript when bluetooth device is disconnected

Tags: applescript, bluetooth, speakers

Spotify continues playing on my Mac when my bluetooth headphones are disconnected (when they go out of range or lose battery for example). I have an AppleScript to pause Spotify, and I want it to be run upon the bluetooth device disconnecting. How can I detect when the bluetooth headphones are disconnected?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44546021/mac-launch-command-when-device-connected-by-bluetooth/44988170#44988170

Answer (score 1):

`system_profiler SPBluetoothDataType` can check you bluetooth status.

There will be connection parameters  `Connected: Yes  or No`

Comment: is there a way to parse the output? I see list of information is showing, it doesn't look like an XML or JSON.

Comment: Try the `-xml` or `-json` options