# Stop media from pausing when bluetooth speaker disconnects

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, safari, bluetooth, big-sur

How can I stop YouTube from pausing itself when I turn off the Bluetooth speaker to which my MacBook is connected?

Comment: @jbis should we assume that YouTube is sending audio to another speaker then the BT one which gets turned off?

Comment: The issue, more specifically, is that when a disconnect occurs, a pause command is issued (the equivalent of clicking the pause button on the keyboard). This will pause media that responds to this API including YouTube Spotify and many other things.

Comment: @JBis you mean the speaker itself is sending "Pause" to the comptuer?

Comment: @theonlygusti No. The speaker is disconnected, the the computer auto issues that command.

Comment: Interestingly I couldn't find this behavior documented anywhere, this was the only reference to it I could find on the internet (or maybe I'm not looking hard enough). From my quick experimentation it indeed seems to be sent by the OS (not chrome), possibly for those that implement `MPMediaPlayback`. And it's only for bluetooth, not wired. Maybe it was done to support airpods?

Comment: Interestingly even bluetooth play/pause seems to work whereas it did not before. I'm not sure exactly when this was introduced, at least > 10.12

Answer (score 1):

According to these two following posts:

- [Launch AppleScript when bluetooth device is disconnected](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/341474/launch-applescript-when-bluetooth-device-is-disconnected)
- [Mac : Launch command when device connected by bluetooth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44546021/mac-launch-command-when-device-connected-by-bluetooth/44988170#44988170)

It seems possible to create an AppleScript that acts on bluetooth disconnect and resumes your music but I have not seen a way to avoid the "pause" command issued on disconnect.